# C++ CImage incomplete type is not alloweed

Tags: c++, mfc

I get incomplete type is not allowed with   CImage image;
I used this:

what went wrong? I never called a class before.

```
using namespace std;
class CImage;


myfunction(hbitmap bmp)
{
    CImage image;
    image.Attach(bmp);
    image.Save("filename.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class CImage;` is a *forward declaration*, it tells the compiler that a class named `CImage` exists, but not how the class is defined (hence incomplete type).

You need to include the header file that defines the `CImage` class.
Try `#include <atlimage.h>` instead of `class CImage;`

---

From the [MSDN CImage class ducumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bwea7by5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> When you create a project using `CImage`, you must define `CString` before you include `atlimage.h`. If your project uses ATL without MFC, include `atlstr.h` before you include `atlimage.h`. If your project uses MFC (or if it is an ATL project with MFC support), include `afxstr.h` before you include `atlimage.h`.
>
> Likewise, you must include `atlimage.h` before you include `atlimpl.cpp`. To accomplish this easily, include `atlimage.h` in your `stdafx.h`.

Comment: #include <CString>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <atlimage.h>      like this?

Comment: @MichaelC #include <atlstr.h> #include <atlimage.h>

Comment: I am using this in a function of mine,  and i get this Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2079 'image' uses undefined class 'GetScreenShot::CImage'                                                   dev_heading_loc_reader c:\users\myoth\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\visual studio stuff\dev_heading_loc_reader\dev_heading_loc_reader\stringcapture.cpp 192

Comment: @MichaelC Please help us to help you and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), without it it's hard to say what is wrong.